# Is it possible to temporally save files in azure function app outside of the temp folder?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to create a different directory than the "temp" one in order to hold temp files?
It is required by some nugget package I use to have an unshared folder for temp files.

Comment: Yes, you can. The root directory of azure function is D:\home\site\wwwroot>

Comment: You can create it and delete it after it been used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The root directory of azure function is D:\home\site\wwwroot>

You can create it and delete it after it been used.

Comment: There's one catch though, `d:\local` (where the TEMP path points to) is a local disk to the VM the function runs on, so much faster than `d:\home` which is remote storage. I would create a folder under `d:\local` and use that, so it doesn't overlap with anything under TEMP.

Comment: @evilSnobu Hi, thanks very much for your supplement. Is there any documentation on this point you mentioned?

Comment: One more thing, if you write to `d:\home\site\wwwroot` your function will restart since it thinks your code has changed and needs to reload. See this issue - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3626. You should write to `%HOME%\data` (persistent across function invocation) or `d:\local` (temporary, may go away at each invocation). And here's more on the filesystem https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system, also here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality#local-drives